# Incapsulated brackets with subequations package

Tags: subequations, empheq

I'm trying to generate a series of equations using incapsulated brackets with this style:
[image: Desidered output]

Key feature I need is that all equations are right aligned and feature their own label. The best I could get is this:

[image: Outcome]

using *empheq* as I report here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations} \label{e:FP}
\begin{empheq}[left={sys \; 1}\Rightarrow\empheqlbrace]{align} 

\begin{empheq}[left={subsys \; 1}\Rightarrow\empheqlbrace]{align} 
x + y = 0\\
\alpha + \beta = 0
\end{empheq} 
\\
A + B = 0 
\end{empheq}
\begin{equation}  \label{e:FP_forces}
l + m = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}  \label{e:FP_forces}
p + q = 0
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Which is pretty far from my desidered result. Can somebody give me a hint? Thanks in advance!

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) please always post full minimal examples not sniplets like this where if we want to test your code we have to add document class and a minimal preamble. (3) make sure your example actually compiles, as far as I recall `empheq` cannot be nested

Comment: I would suggest displaying this in a different way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some visual formatting is necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations} \label{e:FP}
% a few local commands to ease input
\newcommand{\sys}{%
  $\text{sys 1}\implies
  \left\lbrace
  \vphantom{\begin{aligned} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{aligned}}%
  \right.$%
}
\newcommand{\subsys}{%
  $\text{subsys 1}\implies
  \left\lbrace
  \vphantom{\begin{aligned} 1 \\ 1 \end{aligned}}%
  \right.$%
}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{align}
\raisebox{-0.55\height}[0pt][0pt]{\sys}
\raisebox{-0.4\height}[0pt][0pt]{\subsys}
x+y          &= 0 \\
\alpha+\beta &= 0 \\
A+B          &= 0 \\
l+m          &= 0 \\
p+q          &= 0
\end{align}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, the effect is not as nice as I'd require from a display.

Maybe something like the following picture:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations} \label{e:FP}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{alignat}{2}
x+y          &= 0 &\qquad& \text{(sys 1, subsys 1)} \\
\alpha+\beta &= 0 &      & \text{(sys 1, subsys 1)} \\
A+B          &= 0 &      & \text{(sys 1)} \\
l+m          &= 0 \\
p+q          &= 0
\end{alignat}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I thank you very much, in the meantime, to have given to an user (last view of your profile 2 nov 2020).

Comment: @Sebastiano I hadn't seen the question. :-(

Comment: Don't worry...the important thing is that the user has had an answer. After all, I do not know when Jesus will give me time, but I want to leave something good on this Earth.